# Razor Command not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having trouble getting the Razor engine the handle the data_content attribute in the line below.  It treats the @String.Format section as literal string instead of a Razor command.  I have tried @: and @| to no avail.

```
@Html.TextArea("VisitPurpose", null, 
    new { 
        @data_toggle = "hover", 
        @class = "hasPopover input-xxlarge", 
        rows="6", 
        data_placement = "right", 
        data_content = "@String.Format({0}, @Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose)"  
    })
```

Just to be clear this does not work either:

```
 @Html.TextArea("VisitPurpose", null, 
        new { 
            @data_toggle = "hover", 
            @class = "hasPopover input-xxlarge", 
            rows="6", 
            data_placement = "right", 
            data_content = "@Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose)"  
        })
```

The above code renders this on my page.  Instead of the value in my Resource file being rendered, the Razor engine displays it as a literal string.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check scott-pascoe and my questions under my answer? And Please post the content of the 500 internal error. By the way I've suggested to use `data_content = Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose` and not `data_content = "@Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose)"`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are already in "code" mode you don't need the `@` before the `String.Format`:

```
@Html.TextArea("VisitPurpose", null, 
    new { @data_toggle = "hover", 
          @class = "hasPopover input-xxlarge", 
          rows="6", data_placement = "right", 
          data_content = String.Format("{0}", Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose)})
```

By the way with your current code (e.g only the `"{0}"` pattern in your string format) you don't need the `String.Format` at all:

```
@Html.TextArea("VisitPurpose", null, 
    new { @data_toggle = "hover", 
          @class = "hasPopover input-xxlarge", 
          rows="6", data_placement = "right", 
          data_content = Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but removing the @ does not fix it.  The page get 500 server error when doing so.  The String.Format is there just because I thought it would help rending the Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose variable.  The whole point of this tag is to get that Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose variable included in the output.

Comment: What is the type of `Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose`? What is the error message?

Comment: Yes it is a Bootstrap popover.  The resource is used because it needs to display spanish and english text.

Comment: I don't follow you how Boostrap relevant here. So the `Resource.VisitPurpose` is a string property? You have mentioned that you've got 500 server error. What is inside the error? If you are doing an AJAX request check the request in your browser console network tab or in fiddler. You may need to add this to your web.config `<system.web> <customErrors mode="Off"/> </system.web>` to display all the details of the error message.

Comment: You could try replacing the `Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose` with a simple string "Test Visit Purpose".  If that runs successfully (no server 500 error), then look into what `Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose` contains at that point it time. It may be throwing an execption that is getting swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this snippet works.

I was mistaken in my assumption that the Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose variable needed to be surrounded by quotes.  This is why I originally had the String.Format in there.

I removed those quotes and the page rendered.  I then reviewed the page source and low-and-behold the Razor engine put them in for me.

Thanks everyone for your attention and patience.

```
<div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VisitPurpose, @UrgentCareWaitWeb.Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextArea("VisitPurpose", null, new { @data_toggle = "hover", @class = "hasPopover input-xxlarge", rows="6", data_placement = "right", data_content =  Resources.Resource.VisitPurpose   })
        </div>
    </div>
```